# saving facebook image on S3

Tags: php, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, base64

I have seen many posts through which we can upload image on S3, but what if we want to save image from google/facebook , that is something like `graph.facebook.com/abc.img` (suppose it is a valid image)

I have seen a similar post but that uses [Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992721/meteor-saving-images-from-urls-to-aws-s3-storage) but I simply want to use php to save image on s3,
any help in this matter is appreciated Thanks

Comment: downvoters please state teh reason, if I violate anything..

Answer (score 0):

You could use this Facebook SDK PHP Class:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0

And this one for S3:
https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class

1. Get the image from Facebook with the Graph API.
2. Upload it to S3 with the Amazon S3 PHP Class

Should be pretty easy ;)

Comment: which S3 class exactly?