# Meteorjs HTTP call with file send to third party server

Tags: javascript, php, meteor

I have File in Meteor Client side and I want to upload file on the third party server.

```
try {
    const response = HTTP.post('http://localhost:8000/uploadFile', {
                         data: {
                            file:file
                         },                  
                     });
    // console.log(response.content)
    allPagesInImage = JSON.parse(response.content)
    // console.log(allPagesInImage)
} catch (e) {
    SystemLogger.error('Error using Api.ai ->', e);
}
```

I have created Http call for that and send file but it's not working proper and not able to get file on server side

How can i send file to server?

My Third party server is PHP.

Comment: what is the response you're getting? are you getting any errors?

Comment: I am getting no data found

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure you are using the right method for that. I read meteor API doc and the first thing here is that `data` is used for JSON objects. I'm not sure you image qualifies as such. https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html#HTTP-call ... You should start by looking on how to properly retrieve a file using the framework https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099202/how-would-one-handle-a-file-upload-with-meteor Be aware some are outdated and some have evolved....